# How to redirect to another link after following the url?

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a remote location, and I can successfully login, and follow the location of the url to the next page. But from there I need to go to another page(it does not automatically redirect), I need to do it manually. This is the link after the login and follow location `https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Classes/Classwork`, and this is the link I need to manually redirect to `https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Classes/Classwork`

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$url = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  'https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn? ReturnUrl=https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Classes/Classwork');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://homeaccess.katyisd.org');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

$wrapperPage = (curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print $wrapperPage;
?>
```

Comment: Make a new curl session (or maybe you can use the new one, but you need to set the url to the new target), you cannot "redirect".

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you can not redirect much like what would happen if you were using a browser. You'll have to do another cURL session, setting your URL as:

```
https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Classes/Classwork
```

It's not the user which spawns the redirect, its the web server when it sends the HTTP response code 302.